# Issue Getting Error From Server - Instead getting generic error from axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, error-handling, axios

I am writing an authentication handling on my frontend, the login works successfully but I need handling for when it doesn't succeed.

```js
async handleLogin() {
  const response =  axios.post('/api/v1/auth/sign_in', {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
  }).then( (d) => {
    console.log('data: ' + d)
  }).catch( (e) => {
    console.log('error: ' + e)
  })
```

Output in console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in 401 (Unauthorized)
error: Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

I know the server gives a nicer, more accurate error but it never shows up in the response.

In my network tab I get:

```
{"success":false,"errors":["Invalid login credentials. Please try again."]}
```

I would like that in my response. I also get the detailed error in postman.

Any idea what is causing this and how to get the actual server error ?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [handling errors](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)? You would probably see more info if you weren't implicitly converting the `error` to a string. Try `console.error(error)`

Comment: Copying the block in the catch here showed me how to get to the server error: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors thanks.